# php print string without browser transformation

Tags: php, firefox, browser

How to print a string to the browser without any browser transformation?
I need to view the exact characters contained in the string.

A string example maybe:

```
a% 'sd(d) + s, . a/ sàf d ìda
ds fd fd \td ds dsa s\n
\n\r
\n dfsfds fds 6!"£$%&/()=?^<<dss>dsdsa
```

I need that to find in the string invisible characters (such `\n` or `\r`).

I'm still using `htmlentities()`.

Thank's a lot.

Comment: Use `htmlentities()`

Comment: I'm still using htmlentities(). But for the other characters? How to print them? e.g. `\r`?

Comment: Are those literal backslashes, or are they escape sequences that should translate to newline and carriage return?

Comment: You'll probably want to put the output in a `<pre>...</pre>` block, so that the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: I just tried that but when I see the source of the browser, all `<` are converted in `&lt;`. And still with <pre> I don't see the `\r` or `\t` chars

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities()` in a `<pre>` block:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($string);
echo '</pre>';
```

`htmlentities()` ensures that the characters will be shown literally, while `<pre>` preserves line formatting.

Comment: Then those characters aren't really in the string. They're probably just escape sequences in the PHP source code: `\r` is carriage return, `\n` is newline.

Comment: If you want them to be literally in the string, the PHP code needs to use single quotes, or escape them like `\\r`.

Comment: I know that... but I haven't control of string's contents.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. There's no way to tell the difference between `\n` in a string and a line break like you have after `ìda`. You can translate newlines to `\n`, but that will end up translating the other line breaks as well, and everything will end up on one line.